# How do I play a video inside view controller with Swift 2 - 'If let' Error

Tags: ios, avfoundation, swift2

I have imported both mediaPlayer and AVfoundation

```
class AuroraViewController: UIViewController {

var moviePlayer: AVPlayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}




override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


private func playVideo() {
    if let
        path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Aurora", ofType:"mp4"),
         url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path),
         moviePlayer = AVPlayer(contentURL: url) {
            self.moviePlayer = moviePlayer
            moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
            moviePlayer.scalingMode = .AspectFill
            self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
    } else {
        debugPrint("oops, something wrong when playing video.m4v")
    }
}
```

I Get an error about the 'if let': Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSURL'. Is there a different way to do this?

***UPDATE*** Correct code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class myClass: AVPlayerViewController {
private func playVideo() {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Video Name", ofType: "mp4") {
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    }
    else {
        print("Oops, something wrong when playing video.m4v")
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated) 
    playVideo() 
} 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you should do player?.play(), as in my code,sorry for indentation ,but stack overflow didn't saw that as code

Answer (score 0):

The url is not an optional,after you got the path you are sure that there is something and the url is not an optional because there you can have an url where the file doesn't exists, but now you are sure that the file exists because you done if let with the path . Try this

```
 private func playVideo() {
 if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Video Name", ofType: "mp4") {
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
 player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
player?.play()
} 
  else {
print("Oops, something wrong when playing video.m4v")
}
}
```

Comment: If I use this code, I get a bunch more errors. Any other way?

Comment: @yzet00 review the documentation,you did things wrong

Comment: I have Updated the code and checked the documentation. I listed the errors I got. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use "if let" for optional values:

```
if let nonoptional = optional { 
}
```

If the right hand side is not optional, then the if let is just unnecessary.